# Issue with foreign key deployment to SQL server - Code First - Empty foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-3.0

I have rest API in .NET core and EF Core 3.0, I am getting one weird issue.
Below is my entities.

```
[Table(name: "BizObjects")]
public class BizObject
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(06)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; } //FK

    [MaxLength(2)]
    public int ItemIncrement { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    public int SubItemIncrement { get; set; }
    public virtual BizObjectT BizObjectT { get; set; }
}

[Table(name: "BizObjectsT")]
public class BizObjectT
{
    [StringLength(02)]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    #region Primary Key derived from Foreign key for Config tabels                
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey(name: "BizObjectId")]
    [Required]
    public int BizObjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual BizObject BizObject { get; set; }       
    #endregion
}
```

Here is my DbContext.

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options: options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BizObject>()
            .HasOne<BizObjectT>(s => s.BizObjectT)
            .WithOne(g => g.BizObject)
            .HasForeignKey<BizObjectT>(s => s.BizObjectId);
    }

    public DbSet<BizObject> BizObjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BizObjectT> BizObjectsT { get; set; }
}
```

Now, this all works fine. I am able to create migration and I can deploy it to database. my foreign keys works properly in the API.

But the issue that I get is with the SQL server. Here I am not able to find the foreign keys primary table at in relationship window of implementation. even if try to add FK manually, I don't see that table Status.

See below snap.
[image]

I am not sure where the issue is, any suggestion would be a great help.

Thanks.

**Update 1 :**

Here is the entity generated migration.

```
public partial class initial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "BizObjects",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(maxLength: 6, nullable: false),
                Category = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ItemIncrement = table.Column<int>(maxLength: 2, nullable: false),
                SubItemIncrement = table.Column<int>(maxLength: 2, nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_BizObjects", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "BizObjectsT",
            columns: table => new
            {
                BizObjectId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Lang = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 2, nullable: true),
                Text = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_BizObjectsT", x => x.BizObjectId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_BizObjectsT_BizObjects_BizObjectId",
                    column: x => x.BizObjectId,
                    principalTable: "BizObjects",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "BizObjectsT");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "BizObjects");
    }
}
```

The weird thing is if I change database name it will work. But for only first few tables.

let's say I have 10 tables in migration and this **BizObject** is first table, then after changing database name, SQL will have reference of **BizObject** but not of other tables and this is random.

**For reference :**

- VS 2019 version 16.3.0
- SSMS Version 14.0
- SQL server 2014 version 12.0

**Rest API Config :**

- .NET CORE 3.0
- EF Core 3.0

Today I will check all this with new version of SQL server and SSMS and will post updates here later...

**Update 2 :**

Issues seems to be at SQL server or SSMS because I have removed few tables and run the migration, the foreign key didn't work but in the drop down of relational tables, I can see table names which I haven't added in migration.

Comment: SQL script of generated database would be helpful

Comment: migration contains big script, this tables are just for reference here.

Comment: You will have to extract relevant bits from the script then. Specifically, how foreign keys are created. (Search the script for relevant table names / FK names). Any one of the 3 application tiers (EF-> SQL Server-> SSMS) could be the issue. Checking SQL system views (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-foreign-key-properties?view=sql-server-ver15) would help as well.

Comment: @Alex I did that and yes I can see all of my foreign keys. it's present there but I am not able to see them in relation ship window neither I can create any new foreign keys.

Comment: Did you follow the link? Can you post the output of the query?

Comment: yes, I did. let me update my question with more suitable example.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't your FK annotation off? Instead of

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[ForeignKey(name: "BizObjectId")]
[Required]
public int BizObjectId { get; set; }
public virtual BizObject BizObject { get; set; }
```

Sholdn't it be like this:

```
[Required]
public int BizObjectId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(name: "BizObjectId")]
public virtual BizObject BizObject { get; set; }
```

See: [EF Core Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

I also removed the `[Key]` attribute since I am pretty sure it cannot be a key and a foreign key at the same time - You can add a unique index if you like. or if it is indeed used as PK (1:1) you should remove the `[DatabaseGenerated]` attribute since in the child record it cannot be generated by DB.

Comment: " I am pretty sure it cannot be a key and a foreign key at the same time", well I have this strange requirement from client. so I have to..

Comment: Ok, I am just not sure that EF can handle it

Comment: I tried the way you suggested, no luck. it seems issue is with the sql server or ssms

Comment: Can you also try to remove the code from OnModelCreate? Since you are  using attributes in my opinion it is unnecessary (although the migration code looks fine)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think I got the root cause.

It's none other then SSMS. I have updated my SQL server and SSMS to latest versions and it's started working fine. will post more updates later on...